# Remove hardware from "safely remove hardware" list on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a USB wifi card (D-Link DWA-125) on a Windows 7 x64 computer. The problem is that the card appears on the "safely remove hardware" list, but I don't ever want to unplug it, so I would like to remove it from the list.

So far I have only found solutions that mess with the registry (and don't really work properly) or that substitute the safely remove hardware with a third-party software.
Or worse, hide the icon altogether. Yes, I do need the icon from USB drives and phones.

So, is there a "clean" way to remove it from the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.  Those settings are normally hard-coded into the driver.  The registry hack will probably work until you reboot.

Comment: Can you please show a registry hack?

Comment: @Jessica see the other answer.

Comment: I finally located 'Capabilities', and I'm not sure what the next step is.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution here

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30495127/remove-hardware-from-safely-remove-hardware-list.aspx

> This can be achieved by modifying a registry value. So far
> I had no time writing a little tool for this...

> Devices are shown there if they are marked as removable and
> if they do no have the 'surprise removal ok' flag. These are
> bit coded flags:

> From cfgmgr32.h:

> The device capabilities are found in the registry in a value
> named 'Capabilities' under (sample for one of my USB flash
> drives):
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\Vid_058f&Pid_6331\058F091111B

> If you take away 4 from the value or add 80h and then
> refresh the save removal dialog by toggeling the checkbox,
> then the drive is gone.
> But the value is reset when you attach the drive for the
> next time. This is hard coded into the driver and read
> each time the drive is loaded. If you export the modified
> value an reg file then you can silently load it on startup
> by
> regedit /s hidecardreader.reg

> The device id string of your card reader (this
> Vid_058f&Pid_6331\058F091111B thing) is found in the properties
> of the USB device in the device manager. My ListUsbDrives
> tool shows it too (the 'Ctrl  DevID'):
> https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

Update, there is software now that can [hide or unhide usb devices](https://zentimo.com/zentimovsusbsr.htm) from the safely remove list. Unfortunately it is not free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I finally located 'Capabilities', and I'm not sure what the next step is.

Comment: As the linked website has been gone for a long time, I found a more recent explanation: https://www.gog.com/forum/general/remove_a_specific_device_from_safely_remove_hardware

The 'Capabilities' is a bitmask. "4" means removable, "128" means "surprise removal ok". So you can switch a device from "removable" to "surprise removal ok" by adding 124 to the capabilities value. These are indeed defined in Windows' cfgmgf32.h header file: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/cfgmgr32.h