# How to remove my usb device from safely remove hardware and eject list

Tags: usb, eject

I have a third party usb device, when i plugged in it is showing in the safely remove hardware and eject list.

I want to disable that feature. Could any help me out how can achieve it.

Disable through c++ programming also appreciated.

Comment: This any help? http://superuser.com/questions/170949/remove-hardware-from-safely-remove-hardware-list-on-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

That feature is hard coded in Windows and it cannot be removed or disabled, unless you have Windows source code and time to compile it.