# Completely hide overflowed (hidden) items in taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

I have windows 10, and I'm trying to **completely** hide the things in the "overflowed" (hidden) notification icons.

[image]

Here's an image of the startup programs:

[image]

How can I remove all the items in the "hidden" area of the notification icons?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it permanently? What if you need it sometimes?

Comment: I never access it from the bottom icon. And the "safely remove hardware", I never used it in the past, and I don't think I will ever need to use it.

Comment: You have quite few number of icons, why care about that? For the NVIDIA icon you need to look into the NVIDIA app and turn the feature show icon on notification area off, if any. For the safely remove hardware, if you have never used it (and the eject feature in my computer also) then you're extremely extremely lucky to not damage your files or your USB drive any time. I bet if you run Windows check disk 95% chances are you have some bad sectors and/or data lost with many `found.xyz` folders. Unless you format the disk frequently so that the errors are fixed

Comment: Thanks! I have 1 hard drive that is always plugged in. (I use it to store all my music, pictures, etc.) Is there a way to remove that from the list of "Safely remove hardware...?

Comment: @Jessica [Remove hardware from "safely remove hardware" list on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/a/241032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 2 full days of searching, I found an answer. Here's the [source](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hide-or-remove-safely-remove-hardware-tray-icon/).

What you have to do, is create a batch with the following code:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray" /v "Services" /t reg_dword /d 29 /f
systray
```

Then save that in the startup folder.

It will then run every time you turn on the computer. Note: Command will open and close quickly every time the batch file runs.

If you want to install a software that does the same thing, you can do so by going to [this website](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hide-or-remove-safely-remove-hardware-tray-icon/), and download the software listed.

Answer (score 2):

On the start menu select "Settings"

Once open select "Notifications and Actions"

Underneath Quick Actions click "Select Which icons appear on the taskbar"

When that windows opens set "Always show all icons in the Notification area" to OFF, then set any icons you want to see to On and any you Do Not to Off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't want it to be in the hidden part either.

Comment: I have done it on my W10 laptop, items i turned off do not show in the hidden menu any more. You have to first turn off "show all icons in the notification area", then select the ones you do not want shown anywhere.

Comment: When I turn off "Always show all icons in the notification area", then I turn off the selected ones I don't want anymore, they just go in the hidden menu.

Comment: Also, can you answer this comment on your answer please? http://superuser.com/questions/170949/remove-hardware-from-safely-remove-hardware-list-on-windows-7#comment-1353670

Comment: All I can say is it work for me, i don't have any hidden icons showing in taskbar after I did this.