# Remove a USB Drive from the "Safely remove hardware..." list?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I have Windows 10, and I'm trying to remove a 1TB USB hard drive from the "Safely remove hardware..." list.

Here is an image of "Property > Hardware" of the hard drive.

[image]

I want to remove "Eject SimpleDrive USB 2.0" from the list. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

**Update**

I'm trying to get the location of the drive. In Disk Management I right clicked on the grey box entitled "Disk 1" next to the disk graph display. Then I selected Properties. Here's an image of what I got:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not sure how to get the Location, and channel of the hard drive?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I don't think the duplicate answer posted will work for usb devices.

Comment: @Moab Yea, I'm thinking that as well after I looked at this again.

Comment: Can anyone remove the part that it says it's a duplicate if it isn't.

Comment: [Remove hardware from "safely remove hardware" list on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/a/241032)

Comment: In the link you provided, I finally located 'Capabilities', and I'm not sure what the next step is.

Comment: [There is a software solution](http://safelyremove.com/index.htm) I have been using for years, not free thought, USB safely remove can hide any device from the remove list, it is a safely remove replacement in windows